# How to add LinearLayout with rows of imageView In NavigationDrawer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Hi I have the following layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Add The mainmenu-->

    // add a linearLayout with 3 row of imagaeView

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <Mvx.MvxListView
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MenuItems; ItemClick SelectMenuItemCommand"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_menu"
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Problem:**

- How to add a linearLayout with many rows into this Navigational drawer that using MvxListView.

The `NavigationDrawer` is on the left side.

**Questions:**

1. Must I use `FrameLayout`?
2. Can I replace `FrameLayout` with `LinearLayout`?

Comment: Please learn how to add code to your StackOverflow questions. Don't use <pre> it does not work here... Indent your code...

Comment: In the main content view,how many can I put there? the above MainMenu page is placed after FrameLayout, when app start, how come the Main Menu page is above FrameLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DrawerLayout` only supports two child views.

The first element must always be the content view, the second will be what is in the drawer, and you must specify a gravity indicating whether the drawer is coming in from the left or the right.

If you want more than a `ListView` in the drawer, just wrap the contents in another layout such as `RelativeLayout`, `FrameLayout` or `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- add other views here -->

        <Mvx.MvxListView
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MenuItems; ItemClick SelectMenuItemCommand"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_menu"
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#111" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```